# How did Janet Van Dyne survive in the Quantum Realm?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, marvel-cinematic-universe, ant-man-and-the-wasp

I am asking the question that the OP [here](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/90158/why-would-they-assume-janet-van-dyne-was-still-alive) started to but doesn't quite at the end.

Janet Van Dyne was lost in the Quantum Realm for 30 years. In those years, she gained certain abilities. These abilities, however unclear at the moment, do indicate that she can absorb and release quantum energy. Absorbing such energy could probably have kept her alive and fulfilled her body's energy requirements over the years. But she couldn't have learned to do so on the first day or week itself.

Typically a person can survive 3-4 days, maximum one week without water (according to these sources [1](https://www.businessinsider.com/how-many-days-can-you-survive-without-water-2014-5),
[2](https://www.independent.co.uk/life-style/health-and-families/health-news/how-long-a-person-can-survive-without-water-a6873341.html)). How did she survive the first few days in the Quantum Realm without food and water?

---

Some of the comments got me thinking and I developed a theory of sorts. When Hank and Janet embarked on missions, they probably carried food supplies shrunk with them. This would have helped on extended missions. This is however, purely a hypothesis and admittedly there is no in-movie reference to something like this.

Comment: Since she did it in the movie....it's magic! Logical physics don't apply.

Comment: Well I certainly appreciate movie magic as the next person. And I am all for suspending my beliefs when talking about the movie universe. Even then there has to be some sort of in-movie explanation coz the entire plot hinges around the survival of Janet and bringing her back.

Comment: And @Paulie_D, this happens to be a case of "simple biology" ;)

Comment: In an completely different universe where time & space are irrelevant! That seems like explanation enough...simple biology doesn't stand a chance....and don't get me started on how Bruce Banner is still in one piece....that's simple biology too! :)

Comment: not really an answer, but an adjacent trope: https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/NobodyPoops

Comment: haha good one @DForck42! That's a valid one too. But I'm going to discount that in this case coz apparently Janet was absorbing pure energy. There was no residue so to speak.

Comment: May be her body started absorbing energy. Later she could have learnt how it's been done

Comment: @SuryaTej that's quite possible! The process could have started without her knowing about initially, only later she learnt how to control it.

Comment: *cough* Pym Particles *cough* Oh, look over there! There's something growing and shrinking!

Comment: @Kakturus Are you saying what I'm thinking? Supplies shrunk using Pym Particles? Now that could be an extremely plausible in-movie answer! Care to flesh it out?

Comment: @KeyBrdBasher I'm saying that the movie doesn't let logic or physics get in the way of showing cool scenes where lots of things grow or shrink as needed. Seems to me that the people involved in this movie hoped nobody would think about it too hard. I don't think anyone in-universe would have shrunken supplies for her, given that nobody knew she was alive or how to even find her.

Comment: Then I have completely mis-understood what you were implying. My theory is, when Hank and Janet embarked on missions, they probably carried food supplies shrunk with them. This would have helped on extended missions. This is however, purely a hypothesis and admittedly there is no in-movie reference to something like this.

Comment: Maybe Schodinger stuck her in a box, so as long as nobody looked in she was neither alive nor dead.  :D

Comment: It seems that question didn't receive enough attention.

Answer (score 3):

According to [director Payton Reed](http://collider.com/ant-man-and-the-wasp-quantum-realm-explained-peyton-reed/), there’s food in the Quantum Realm... possibly from a civilization:

> [Janet Van Dyne] has this spear things and these other items that feel like it’s from some sort of culture. There’s something going down. It’s not just some wasteland.
>
> [...] There is definitely a shot as Hank and Janet are blasting out of the Quantum Realm where it appears there might be some sort of civilization down there.
>
> There’s definitely a specific backstory to what Janet Van Dyne has been doing the past thirty years… There’s some great food down there, guys. The food scene in the Quantum Realm is not to be believed (laughs).

I believe the shot they're talking about is this one (which I got from [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/198600/82909)):

[image]

In Endgame:

> Ant-Man only experienced 5 hours in the Quantum Realm. Everyone else spent even less time there. Therefore, we don't know any more about what's actually in the Quantum Realm except that it can be used for time travel.

Answer (score 0):

The Quantum Realm is a reality where all concepts of time and space become cease to exist as you shrink for all eternity. The idea that you can't survive 3-4 days without food is irrelevant when you're in a reality where time ceases to exist.

Comment: Could you [edit] in any evidence to support your theory?

Answer (score 0):

The Quantum Realm's counterparts in comic books are a variety of microverses that actually have life and edible food so the same may apply to it.  On the flip side it's definite that Janet acquired superpowers from her lengthy exposure to the environment down there.  We can dismiss the idea that time didn't pass down there.  She aged.

Answer (score -1):

Completely spit-balling here...  There my be something to do with metabolism and sizing...  I.e., when Scott gets big, he has to sleep for a long time.  Maybe at extremely small sizes, the body metabolizes a lot slower and a subatomic sized person can survive for 30 years on the energy consumed in a single day??? There is something to be said for suspend your disbelief...

If you're wondering how he eats and breathes 
 And other science facts,
 Just repeat to yourself "It's just a show,
 I should really just relax

Comment: Welcome to M&TV. While this is a nice theory, we generally prefer answers sourced with facts (i.e in this case a quote from the film or a creator). I recommend  taking our [tour](https://movies.stackexchange.com/tour) and visiting the [help center](https://movies.stackexchange.com/help) to get familiar with site. Cheers!

Comment: I really like your train of thought GT_Bob. I reckon, you could have a full fledged answer if you spend some time fleshing it out.

Answer (score -1):

In the Quantum Realm, 1 Hour is equivalent to 1 year so in reality it was just a day, and a half. Which is why Ant-Man also did not starve by Endgame's first Minute.

Comment: Why does Janet Van Dyne look so old then?

Comment: She would age the same as she did in Earth time.